React Date picker keyboard navigation is not working
I'm using select time only of react-datepicker.
When I'm trying to navigate using keyboard, pressing the tab is opening the time picker, but next tab, is focusing on the last time, which is 11:45 instead of selected time.
Navigation using arrow keys are working as well. Instead of changing the time, it's scrolling the time option dropdown.
I'm able to navigate between the times using tab.
This is one of the code snippet.
<DatePicker
            //ts-ignore
            selected={selected}
            tabIndex={0}
            ref={timeSlotRef}
            calendarClassName={calenderClassName}
            onChange={onChange}
            name={name}
            showTimeSelect={showTimePicker || false}
            timeInputLabel="Time"
            minTime={minTime || undefined}
            maxTime={maxTime || undefined}
            dateFormat={showOnlyTimePicker ? 'hh:mm aa' : 'yyyy-MM-dd h:mm aa'}
            placeholderText={placeHolderText || 'time'}
            showDisabledMonthNavigation={true}
            // onKeyDown={(e: any) => e.preventDefault()}
            onFocus={(e: any) => e.target.blur()}
            open={open}
            disabled={isDisabled}
            showTimeSelectOnly={showOnlyTimePicker || false}
            timeIntervals={timeIntervals}
            timeCaption="Time" // header text, as defalt it's hidden
          />


